# Submitting Article for Translation through Test Class causing internal error

Tags: apex, unit-test, knowledge

I'm trying to test a class which queries for translations of an article. This is the setup functionality in the test class to create an article with a translation.

```
Article_Type__kav af_1 = new The_Source__kav(Title='article', URLName = 'test-article1');
insert af_1;

The_Source__kav article = [SELECT Id, KnowledgeArticleId FROM Article_Type__kav WHERE Id = :af_1.Id];
KbManagement.PublishingService.publishArticle(article.KnowledgeArticleId, true);


KbManagement.PublishingService.submitForTranslation(article.KnowledgeArticleId, 'es_US', test_user.Id, DateTime.now().addDays(7));
```

The final line causes the error: "System.UnexpectedException: internal error." test_user is already created and has the System Administrator profile. Am I going about creating the translation correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer helps anybody breaking their head over this in the future.

In my scenario, the error was coming up because my test user did not have the "Knowledge User" permission.

`test_user.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true;`

Once this was set, the internal error was no longer seen!!